# Why does C have these weird translation limits (section 2.2.4.1)?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, programming-languages, limit

I was just browsing the C standard the other day, and the chapter about translation limits really had me stumped. Why are some translation limits 2^n, others 2^n+1 and others 2^n-k (for some small k)?

Here are just some examples:

- 15 nesting levels of compound statements, iteration control
  structures, and selection control structures
- 31 declarators nested by parentheses within a full declarator
- 32 expressions nested by parentheses within a full expression
- 31 significant initial characters in an internal identifier or a
  macro name
- 511 external identifiers in one translation unit
- 509 characters in a logical source line
- 257 case labels for a switch statement (excluding those for any
  nested switch statements)

Why isn't everything simply a power of two?

Comment: Which version of the C-Standard are you referring to, please?

Comment: Also this typically are minimum restrictions an implementation shall meet.

Comment: The C11 Draft gives other value in "*5.2.4.1 Translation limits*" (http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.2.4.1) Also it states "*Implementations should avoid imposing fixed translation limits whenever possible.*"

Comment: "The Annotated ANSI C Standard" (C89/C90)

Comment: Memory was a lot scarcer in the 1980s.

Comment: Why are they "weird" ? Looks very natural to me for them to be a function of power of two...

Comment: @EugeneSh.  I think he is talking about the `k` (as a small number ).

Comment: I would say the `k` is reserved for some implementation overhead.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Why 511 or 509 instead of 512? Why 257 instead of 256?

Comment: It's like if a string was encoded using the content+length byte, it's max length would be 255 rather than 256. In the `case` there is one `else` case. Which leaves additional 256 labels available, so if encoded with 1 byte, it can operate with 257. And similar reasoning can be applied to any of these restrictions.

Comment: The 509 line length limit is likely specified to allow up to 2 newline characters, as well as terminating null in a 512 byte buffer.

Comment: @owacoder Or a terminating `\0` byte and two bytes of line length.

Comment: @FUZxxl - But if you have a terminating null, why bother with the line length?

Comment: Only and current C standard is C11. Others are not valid anymore, so no use toi even think about them.

Comment: @owacoder Some languages use strings with a length *and* a \0 terminator so they are both safe and can be passed to C code.

Comment: @Olaf The valid standard is the one the currently used compiler is set to comply.

Comment: @Olaf: At least life told me it's not *that* easy ... ;-)

Comment: @Olaf I don't share your opinion. C11 adoption is slow and for various reasons many people still program against C99 or C89, so it's interesting and important to talk about these.

Comment: @FUZxxl - C itself has no string length stored, which is what the OP is talking about.

Comment: @owacoder The compiler might be implemented in a different language. For example, Compcert is implemented in Coq.

Comment: @FUZxxl - All right. ;)

Comment: @EugeneSh.: No. Acompiler does not set a standard, but at most a norm. The C **standard** is released by the IEEE C commitee (WG14 IIRC) and there is only one valid at a time. Previous versions are withdrawn with a new release.

Comment: @FUZxxl: If it comes to a question taggen only C and without clear reference, one has to rely on the current version. You do not care what you said as a 5 years old, don't you? It simply makes no sense to wonder about outdated version now, as times and constraints have change - by some decades.

Comment: @Olaf No, please don't! They are helpful to future readers.

Comment: @FUZxxl: My bad. too late. Ill answer again and we just remove the rat's tail, ok?

Comment: @ameyCU: "OP" means "Original Poster". Shorter than "asker" or "questioner" (if the latter actually is a valid word)

Comment: @Olaf I do care. Many programs are written against C89 and won't even compile with a C11 compiler. It's important to care about older C standards as they describe a language that is more or less subtly different from today's C. It's also interesting to understand the design decisions for the specified translation limits.

Comment: @Olaf  Thanks again :)

Comment: @FUZxxl: That was not my point actually. It was especially for the question. OP clearly asks present tense, not past and the present standard has loosended the limits very much compared to the cited text. But due to the tense, an unaware reader has to conclude they are from the current release.

Comment: @Olaf Oh, yeah. Would you also assume C11 for a question tagged [C] and [windows], even though MSVC isn't even C99 compliant?

Comment: @FUZxxl: No, I would not assume C at all for MSVC. But that is my personal opinion. But this question **is** about the standard, not a particular implementation. If it was "why does MSVCC does impose strange limitations", things very different and I would not have complained. The same if it was past tense.

Comment: Roughly: +1 for function body, +1 for root declarator, +0, +1 for \0, +1 for main, +3 for \r\n\0, -1 for default.

Comment: @hanspassant: you don't think 509 has to do with the logic to detect trigraphs? A _logical_ source line shouldn't include \r

Answer (score 1):

> Why isn't everything simply a power of two?

To me, most of them look like 2<sup>n</sup> - 1, even the line length, once you add carriage return and line feed.

These are minimum limits, by the way. Compilers are allowed to exceed them.

Comment: And what about the number of case labels?

Comment: Is it a violation of the standard to write a code exceeding these limits?

Comment: @FUZxxl 256 labels + default maybe

Comment: @JeremyP  I thought of this, too, but `default` is not a `case` label.

Comment: @JeremyP Maybe so you can switch over every possible value in a `char`?

Comment: @EugeneSh. No. The C compiler cannot call it Cxx compliant though (for whatever C version, C11 has higher limits).

Comment: @EugeneSh. No, but then your code is no longer “strictly confirming.”